# FFmpeg insufficient thread locking only when deploying application using homebrew

Tags: c++, dll, deployment, ffmpeg, homebrew

I have the strangest bug of my life.
I have installed ffmpeg using homebrew. I use it from a dll.
I have set a lock manager because I use ffmpeg from multiple threads.

In Engine.h:

```
class EXPORT_LIB Engine
{
public:
    static int initEngine();    
    static int closeEngine();
};
```

In Engine.cpp:

```
static int ff_lockmgr(void **mutex, enum AVLockOp op)
{
if (NULL == mutex)
    return -1;

switch(op)
{
case AV_LOCK_CREATE:
{
    *mutex = NULL;
    boost::mutex * m = new boost::mutex();
    *mutex = static_cast<void*>(m);
    break;
}
case AV_LOCK_OBTAIN:
{
    boost::mutex * m =  static_cast<boost::mutex*>(*mutex);
    m->lock();
    break;
}
case AV_LOCK_RELEASE:
{
    boost::mutex * m = static_cast<boost::mutex*>(*mutex);
    m->unlock();
    break;
}
case AV_LOCK_DESTROY:
{
    boost::mutex * m = static_cast<boost::mutex*>(*mutex);
    delete m;
    break;
}
default:
    break;
}
return 0;
}


int Engine::initEngine()
{
    int res = -1;
    res = av_lockmgr_register(&ff_lockmgr);
    av_register_all();
    av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_QUIET); // ERROR, PANIC
    // Av lock manager success
    if( res == 0 ) {
        res = MULTITHREAD;
    }
    else {
        res = SINGLETHREAD;
    }
    return res;
}

int Engine::closeEngine()
{
    int res = 0;
    res = av_lockmgr_register(NULL);
    return res;
}
```

So far so good, everything works as expected.

When I deploy my app using CMake fix_bundle. I have an error message

**insufficient thread locking around avcodec_open/close()**

If I compile ffmpeg by hand in a custom location, when I deploy the app everything works as expected. What is wrong with homebrew ?

Comment: First you need to make sure that all libraries are taken from the correct location when you build bundle.

Comment: Error that you have described, occurs if the lock is not working correctly. You can add a temporary logging `boost::mutex * m = new boost::mutex(); std::cout << "create mutex"; ...` `std::cout << "try to lock..."; m->lock(); std::cout<<"lock mutex";` etc.

Comment: If have also tried with pthread, it is working when I use my own ffmpeg, but not the one with homebrew